# How to test whether a node contains a namespace

Tags: xml, perl, xpath

Given the XML snippet bellow how do I tell the difference between

```xml
<entry xmlns:georss="...">
```

with the children

```xml
<title>fileName1.jpg</title>
```

and

```xml
<entry><title type="text">fileName.pdf</title></entry>
```

I'm using [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML) to loop through the `<entry>` but this gets each one so the connection between `<type>` and `<link>` is lost. I need to test at the `<entry>` level not the child `<type>` level

Can you test if entry node has georss namespace?

Something like this gets the value of `<type>`

```
foreach my $Entry ($dom->findnodes("//dft:feed/dft:entry")) {

     foreach my $Images ($dom->findnodes("//dft:title[not(\@type='text')]", $Entry)) {
         my $ImageVal = $Images->textContent;
          ####  This finds all the Images

     }

}
```

XML Snippet

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss">

  <entry xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss/10" xsi:schemaLocation ="http://www.url1.net/path/ http://www.url2.net/path/11  http://www.url3.net/path/23" >
    <title>fileName1.jpg</title>
    <link href="PathTo/fileName1.jpg" />
  </entry>

  <entry xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss/10" xsi:schemaLocation ="http://www.url1.net/path/ http://www.url2.net/path/11  http://www.url3.net/path/23" >
    <title>fileName2.jpg</title>
    <link href="PathTo/fileName2.jpg" />
  </entry>

  <entry>
    <title type="text">fileName.pdf</title>
    <link type="application/pdf"  href="PathTo/fileName.pdf" />
  </entry>

</feed>
```

Comment: Please [edit] and provide a [mcve] that includes parsing the example XML.

Comment: You need to inlcude XML tags in inline code markup using `\`<foo>\``. [I had done that for you](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/38894663/2), but you overwrote my edit.

Answer (score 1):

> Can you test if entry node has `georss` namespace?

There is no data in your example that is in the `georss` namespace. Everything is in the namespace `http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom` defined in the `feed` element. The definition `xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss/10"` just specifies a namespace prefix `georss`, but that prefix is never used

You need to create an [`XML::LibXML::XPathContext`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML::XPathContext) object attached to the `XML::LibXML` document that allows you to specify namespace abbreviations. The code looks like below

Note that I've also had to fix your XML data to include a definition of the `xsi` namespace, as without it the data is not well-formed

You shouldn't make a habit of adding `//` at the start of every XPath expression. It forces the XPath engine to unnecessarily search the entire document each time, and an explicit XPath from the root is better practice. It also produces the wrong result with your XPath `//dft:title[not(@type='text')]` because you're starting the search from the root each time and ignoring the `entry` context node. Just `dft:title[not(@type="text")]` is correct

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use XML::LibXML;
use XML::LibXML::XPathContext;

my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml( location => 'feed.xml' );

my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($dom);
$xpc->registerNs( dft    => 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' );
$xpc->registerNs( georss => 'http://www.georss.org/georss/10' );

for my $entry ($xpc->findnodes('/dft:feed/dft:entry')) {

     for my $images ($xpc->findnodes('dft:title[not(@type="text")]', $entry)) {

         my $image_val = $images->textContent;

         print $image_val, "\n";
     }
}
```

#### output

```
fileName1.jpg
fileName2.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you for the tips.  No your right I had left out the '<georss:where>' as it isn't required by me. What I do need  is to run 2 loops 1 for '<entry>' with child / images and 2nd loop for the pdf files how might I do this?